# Change UIImageView center point on scroll of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

I'm attempting to create a very simple parallax effect when the user scrolls a UIScrollView. I'm using the scrollViewDidScroll method on my scrollview, thats all working.  I can log an everything from that method so I know it is being fired off when the UIScrollView is scrolled.  The issue is any changes I attempt to make to the contents of UIScrollView fails.  Possibly a rendering issue?  Does a UIScrollView not re-render its contents during scrolling?

I have tried changing the UIImageView(imageView)'s frame and center point, nothing is working. Any ideas on what might be going on, I'm not getting any sort of errors or anything.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)body {

    float y = body.contentOffset.y;

      imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageView.bounds.size.width/2, (imageView.bounds.size.height/2) - y/2);

    // Tried this as well
    //[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView.bounds.size.width, imageView.bounds.size.height + (y * 2))];

    NSLog(@"We are scrolling...");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, I actually needed to grab the instance of the ImageView within the ScrollView using.  Anyone else trying to figure this out, I did it a little hacky but it works.

```
/* Paralax Scrolling */
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)body {

    float y = body.contentOffset.y;

    // When adding (body) image view to scroll view I assigned a tag of 100 to it.
    [body viewWithTag:100].center = CGPointMake([body viewWithTag:100].bounds.size.width/2, ([body viewWithTag:100].bounds.size.height/2) + y/2);

}
```